# Is it possible to draw internal border boundaries (in a way window-divider-first-pixel draws it)

Tags: window

I use `internal-border-width` with `right-divider-width` to add some "light" within the frame and visually separate windows.  By setting `internal-border` (background) and `window-divider` (foreground) to the same color with distinct colors for `window-divider-first|last-pixel` I'm able to achieve pretty nice effect of having internal "frames" for the windows, but `window-divider` settings allow only inner separation between the windows (called for some reason "right", and bottom).  I can't find any setting that would allow me to draw similar lines (as `window-divider-first|last-pixel` do) at the outer (leftmost, rightmost and top) borders of the windows.  The question is -- is it possible to achieve?